# Is it possible to get the assistantship(TA/RA) before landed in USA for PhD program?

Tags: phd, united-states

We know that most of the PhD students would not get scholarship and they need to do work as assistanceship in USA. Is it possible to get these assistanceship before reaching into USA? If so, then how?

Comment: In many cases, an assistantship is offered alongside the offer of admission.  If it's not, then it may be a situation where assistantships may or may not be available, on a competitive basis, depending on the teaching needs from term to term.

Comment: In any case, the answer to "how" would be "ask the department".

Comment: @NateEldredge "alongside the offer of admission"--- you mean from PhD first semester assistantships are offered?

Comment: What field are you in?

Comment: Nate means that your offer of acceptance into the program would ordinarily tell you about funding - if you are guaranteed funding for some number of years, how you will be funded, etc. It would be very unusual (though it happens) to be offered and then accept an admission offer that does not discuss funding. In my view, a PhD acceptance without a funding offer should be considered *not* an acceptance.

Comment: @NateEldredge in one university TA form asking student ID? So, I am not student till now of that university, how to get student ID?

Comment: You already got a general answer: Discuss technical matters such as student ID with the department, not with strangers online. And work in your English grammar, you will need it when you arrive to your university in the US.

Comment: Is this an XY problem where you are wondering about a visa issue?

Comment: Note that you won't be able to get a student visa to enter the US without proof that you've been admitted to a university and that you have the financial resources to pay for your program of study and support yourself.  For most international students, an assistantship is awarded at the same time that the student is admitted to the graduate program at a university.

Comment: I really don't think this question is sufficiently clear without modification. Is it asking whether one can get a TA or RA offer while not being physically resident in the US? About visa issues? Or whether one can officially start a position without being present? All three have different answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Details will differ between disciplines.

In Computer Science, most reputable, good programs will not offer admission to the Ph.D. program without assured funding, at least for the beginning two or three years. The exceptions among good institutions are mainly programs with a different flavor, e.g. those aimed at students that already work in the industry and feel the need to get a degree.

Assured funding means either an RA-ship or a TA-ship, or a combination of both. There is an expectation that once a student has entered a research group, usually after two years, the research group will pay for the student out of grant money. This expectation is not reflected in an admission letter. It is possible that a student is judged by all potential groups to be a bad risk, in which case the student will no longer receive funding and is expected to leave the program with a "consolation" M.S. degree. This is a rare occurrence.

In other disciplines, funding is more limited and many Ph.D. students will have to self-finance at least parts of their studies.

This means for you that if you receive an offer letter for admission into the Ph.D. program, it should come with initial financing in Computer Science / Electrical Engineering and a few other disciplines. If it does not, then this usually means that there is no RA or TA-ship available. If funding is only offered for one year or two years, that does not mean that you will loose support after this time, but the admitting university is not guaranteeing anything in case you turn out to be a bad student. You are not running significant risks if you accept such an offer. If your offer does not include any offer of financing, then this means that it will be difficult for you to find financial support from the department.

Comment: What does mean of significant risk? Give some example.

Comment: You need to be really bad or behave quite poorly. Or you acquire a criminal record, have lied about yourself, ...